# UITabbar controller badge colour

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have 4 tabs on `tabBar`, on `4th button` I set `badge` with `orange colour`, and when I click on `4th button` `badge` `colour` is changing into `gray` from `orange`. I need to keep it `orange` even after `4th button` clicked.

```
func onMoreTabRefresh() {
    if let tabbarItem = tabBarViewController.tabBar.items?[RootTab.More.rawValue] {
        tabbarItem.badgeValue = "8"
    }
}

UITabBarItem.appearance().badgeColor = UIReferences.Color.badgeOrangeColor
```

Comment: add some of your code.

Comment: In the viewDidLoad I am setting badge colour to orange. @Kuldeep

Comment: did you try  `UITabBarItem appearance  setTitleTextAttributes:`

Comment: setTitleTextAttributes is for items in tabBar not for badges I guess @Kuldeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Storyboard select your tab in which you required to add badge then select attribute and then below the badge property it shows the badge color property as per show below image.

[image]

or programatically:-

```
 self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![0].badgeColor = .black
```

Thank you.

Comment: I am doing it programmatically , i am not working in storyboard , can you send me code

Comment: @RameshKumar can you please try with default color? Like this:-                
   UITabBarItem.appearance().badgeColor = .green

Comment: @RameshKumar please attach your code in which this statement is use:-UITabBarItem.appearance().badgeColor = .green

Comment: I Have added in viewDidLoad

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 

        
        UITabBarItem.appearance().badgeColor = UIReferences.Color.badgeOrangeColor
      
        
        tabBarViewController.view.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        tabBarViewController.selectedIndex = RootTab.Journal.rawValue
        tabBarViewController.tabBar.itemPositioning = .fill
        
        onMoreTabRefresh()
        onLeafTabRefresh()
    }